# How to delete a calendar using ical4j?

Tags: java, icalendar, caldav, ical4j

Is it possible at all? 
I can create the new one using

```
(CalDAVCollection)collection.createCalendar(httpClient);
```

But not sure how to delete it. I have a calendar name and host and full config but not sure how to delete it.

Any ideas?

Comment: [ical4j](https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j) is an iCalendar library and
doesn't even provide a `CalDAVCollection` type.
Presumably you are talking about
[caldav4j](https://github.com/caldav4j/caldav4j)?

Comment: The question is how to delete calendar using ical4j....